# Cannot Read XML file from https:// site

Tags: xml, r, https

Running R 3.2.0, R Studio 0.99.441, Windows 7 32-bit, XML package 3.98-1.2

I am trying to read a XML file from the site below using XML package, and xmlTreeParse but keep getting an error.

https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml

```
> fileURL <- "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
> doc <- xmlTreeParse(fileURL, useInternal = TRUE)
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: 'https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml'
```

I also tried download.file () with xmlTreeParse

```
download.file(fileURL, destfile = "data.xml")
doc <- xmlTreeParse("data.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
```

When I do this there is no immediate error but the varibale 'doc' has no structure and I'm not sure how to read it from this point.

Comment: Because of the https try to add `method = "curl"` argument to the `download.file` function. The problems should be there. I have a Mac, I can't see the differences between curl and no curl because Mac works only with the curl options. Let us know if it works.

Comment: > download.file(fileURL, destfile = "data.xml", method = "curl")
Warning messages:
1: running command 'curl  "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"  -o "data.xml"' had status 127 
2: In download.file(fileURL, destfile = "data.xml", method = "curl") :
  download had nonzero exit status  
I still have to structure when i run my rootNode[[1]] I get back the entire xml document

Answer (score 1):

Remove `s` from `https` :

```
fileURL <- "http://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2Frestaurants.xml"
fileURL <- sub('https', 'http', fileURL)
doc <- htmlParse(fileURL)
```

Comment: why does the s break it?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
library(XML)
fileURL <- "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/simple.xml"
download.file(fileURL, destfile = "data.xml", method = "curl")
doc <- xmlTreeParse("data.xml", useInternalNodes = TRUE)
rootNode <- xmlRoot(doc)
```